How do I rig a swashplate?
This gif gives a general idea of what I am trying to achieve under 'rest conditions'.

The problem is that this rig stops working once I tilt the swashplate, thus defeating the entire purpose of a swashplate:

Currently I have an IK constraint driving the arm, while the rotation of the swashplate is separately driven by a locked track constraint. The locked tracked constraint stops working the moment the swashplate is rotated.
I can't figure out a way to set up an IK constraint to drive the rotation of the swashplate, while still letting the non-rotating part of the swashplate determine the orientation. For instance if I flipped the bone for the swashplate, parent it to the bones of the arm, and give it the IK constraint, I will no longer be able to affect it's tilt.
Any ideas?


Yes please include a blend file https://blend-exchange.com

I threw up the blend file. The armature is a little different from more failed experimentation.

I have come up with a "solution" that sort of works. It is quite finicky and it seems to lag out of position occasionally, so hopefully someone else can come up with a better solution:

The arm is controlled by an IK constraint which targets a bone that is parented to the rotating swashplate bone. Bones in the IK chain have their axes of rotation locked appropriately.
Simultaneously, the rotating swashplate is controlled by a Locked Track constraint which targets a bone parented to the end of the arm.
Essentially, I have two different constraints, each targeting a bone parented to the opposite chain of bones.
Finally, I have another Locked Track constraint which merely adjusts the orientation of the connector which attaches the the arm to the rotating swashplate.
Here you can see how this arrangement mostly works, but because each constraint is iterating off of the other constraint, the alignment is never quite perfect:

"Working" rig:

